# How can I force user to download file on a specific directory?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, download, angular8

Ciao,

I'm working on a Web Application with ASP.NET Core and Angular 8.
My goal is download a file and force the user to download it on specific folder (it is a network folder).

how can I achieve this?

Actually I download my file with this code in Angular:

```
...
this.myService.download().subscribe
(
   // res is of type HttpResponse<Blob>
   res => {
       var collegamento = document.createElement("a");
       collegamento.href = URL.createObjectURL(res.body);
       collegamento.download = "myfile.extension";
       collegamento.click();
   }
)
...
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: It's the users pc.  Why should you have any control over where they choose to save the file?

Comment: In other words, there's no way to do this. The only way is to give your backend access to the network folder and have it save the file there.

Comment: @Taplar I know it is a requirement of client.

Comment: @ChrisG thank you, It is a good workaround. There is a way to recommend the user to save on specific path? I imagine a SaveAs window with raccomanded path or something like that.

Comment: Many users have their browsers set to automatically download to their Downloads folder, they don't even see a "Save As" window, let alone one with a chosen path.

Comment: Assuming that your server is able to access the local network drive: You can click that "Save" Button and your backend logic will store the file on a network drive?

Comment: @Daniel Hi, thank you for your response. I need to verify that this can be possible for our infrustructure.